# Issue with parsing text file in pandas

Tags: python-3.x, csv, pandas

I have the following text file which I would like to load in python:

```
                cabin embarked     boat   body  
0                  B5        S        2    NaN   
1             C22 C26        S       11    NaN   
2             C22 C26        S      NaN    NaN   
3             C22 C26        S      NaN  135.0   
4             C22 C26        S      NaN    NaN   
5                 E12        S        3    NaN   
6                  D7        S       10    NaN   
7                 A36        S      NaN    NaN   
8                C101        S        D    NaN
```

Based on the response to a similar question that I received, I tried the following:

```
df = pd.read_fwf("test.csv", header=0, index_col=0)
```

and it worked fine. 
But the following doesnt work:

```
pd.read_csv("test.csv", sep="\s{2,}", header=0, index_col=0, engine="python")
```

I get the following error:

```
ValueError: Expected 4 fields in line 2, saw 5
```

Given the fact that sep="\s{2,}" considers the fields to be separated by 2 or more whitespaces,

`line 2 (0                  B5        S        2    NaN),`

should have been parsed without any problem. Also, I see only 4 fields in line 2 (excluding the row index which is taken care of by index_col=0); which is the 5th field that the error is referring to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`cabin embarked` is only one space apart and gets parsed as a single string.

`pd.read_csv` is given some latitude and figures that there is an empty space for an index.

```
                cabin embarked     boat   body  
# ^             ^                  ^      ^
# field 1       field 2           field 3 field 4
# this row establishes expectations


0                  B5        S        2    NaN  
^                  ^         ^        ^    ^ 
field 1            field 2   field 3  fd 4 field 5
```

And that's the error.  Row 1 established precedence of 4 fields and row 2 shows 5.

Comment: I see. So, the header decides the number of fields. Also, the index column is considered as a field as well. great! Thanks.